# New User unable to login via ssh

Tags: ssh, rhel, login

I'm trying to set up two new accounts in a Redhat 6.10 environment. The first account that I created works fine no issues. I used the same steps and the second account is unable to login via ssh with putty.

Error Message:

```
Access denied Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
```

What I have tried: Make both of the users have the same password, both are in the same group and that group is in the `sshd_config` file. The only difference between the accounts are the name which are both 4 characters long. Any ideas on what I am missing? I have also reset both account passwords just in case I missed something. I'm assuming somewhere a permission issue is causing this but not sure where to start looking.

Edit:

Errors message from `/var/log/secure` file:

```
error: PAM: Authentication failure for <user> from <myComputer>
pam_unix(sshd:auth): conversation failed
pam_unix(sshd:auth): auth could not identify password for [user]
error: ssh_msg_send: write
```

Comment: Similar thread on SF: https://serverfault.com/questions/346397/pam-unixsshdauth-auth-could-not-identify-password-for-admin-sshd6968

Answer (score 1):

First of all - always check logs. The `/var/log/secure` will log every attempt to login with `ssh` by default. You can open it with `tail -f /var/log/secure` and try to login as a user in a separate window.

Next, make sure the user has a valid shell. You can check it with `grep username /etc/passwd`. To change shell to bash use `chsh username -s /bin/bash`.

Make sure the user has a home directory. His home directory is also listed in `/etc/passwd`, and you can check it with `su - username` and then `cd ~`. If his home folder does not exist, you should create it, but make sure to set the correct ownership. Though lack of home directory should not prevent this user from loging in.

Check your `sshd_config` if your user listed in `DenyUsers`. If it is not, try to add it to `AllowUsers`. If your sshd_config does not have it, the syntax is:

```
AllowUsers username
```

Comment: Added messages from the secure log (thanks). The shell is correct and the user does a home directory. We have a group sshusers that is stated as AllowGroup sshusers. I have also tried just putting the individual users and it didn't work.

Comment: @TheAirborneranger I updated the answer, check the `DenyUsers` / `AllowUsers`

Comment: Yea we have AllowUsers and didn't work. It looks like a Pam issue from what the logs are saying.

Comment: @TheAirborneranger do you have any custom Pam modules? And... Did you try turning it off and on again?..

Comment: Also does it only affect password auth? Are you able to login with a key?

Comment: I'll be honest I have no idea about the custom Pam modules. I didn't set up this environment. I have not turned Pam of and back on. This seems to only affect password auh, since I have had some users able to login via smart card reader.

Comment: @TheAirborneranger can you create a third user and can it login?

Comment: No I can't login with the 3rd new user. Although I have delete both the first and second user and recreated them. I still am able to login with the first user but not the second....

Comment: @TheAirborneranger do your users have any specific characters in the usernames?

Comment: As of right now the username names are grayc, stida, user3.

Comment: How do you add the users?

Comment: useradd -G *groupname* *username* then a passwd for the account password.

Comment: Can you try to add a user in his own group and check if it works? Simply `useradd username`

Comment: No it doesn't work. I tried a few things other than just making the account. I added the users to AllowUsers on the sshd_config file. I am able to login with the user when I physically touch the server, but not by ssh even after adding them the sshd_config file.

Comment: Update the software. Reboot the server. I am getting out of ideas, sorry :c

Comment: I am too... lol  I appreciate the help! I can't reboot until tonight. I'm not a system admin so i'll let them do the updating, but damn is this annoying, thank you!